# Angular: change URL for the same controller

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/:placeId', {templateUrl: 'client/partials/menu.html', controller: MenuCtrl}).
    when('/look/refill', {templateUrl: 'client/partials/refill.html', controller: RefillCtrl}).
    when('/look/orderCart', {templateUrl: 'client/partials/orderCart.html', controller: OrderCartCtrl}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/0'});
}]).
```

I need to add link on the first page and when you click it, URL should be changed(for axeample add 1 in the and of URL) but page should be left the same, without any changes and reloading. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: You are doing URLs wrong if you wish to change the path but not load a new page or some new content...

Comment: Why do you want such a functionality? Surely there is a better way to do whatever you want to do...

Comment: Because I need when you click button "back" I need to return on the same page, but to get previous state of page.

Comment: how can I do it other way?

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you want

```
when('/:placeId', {templateUrl: 'client/partials/menu.html', controller: MenuCtrl, reloadOnSearch: false})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not change the URL, I mean using this approach I can link to rhis page again... but URL will be the same without changes :(

Comment: do you have $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) ?

Comment: How can I use it can't understand documentation from angular - could you help me please?

Comment: Just add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) after your route declaration, then get server to send back the corresponding template. In your case, server should have api for returning client/partials/menu.html when requested '/:placeId'.

Comment: with this mode it rewrite my url from http://localhost/OscarWilde/confCart/#/0 to http://localhost/OscarWilde/confCart/#%2F0 and show nothing Oo

Comment: add this as well                     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');